# SARA Security Auditor Alternative

Tags: security, networking, scanning

I have attempted to install and run [Sara](http://www-arc.com/sara/), but it seems that the software is broken. I could get it to run on 127.0.0.1, but it seems that no network packets ever leave the current computer that it is installed on.

It tests for known security holes in a network. It was based on an older software SATAN. Is there another free alternative to this program?

I did not see anything listed in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/3855/must-have-networking-security-tools).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few network security auditors out there.  Some will just check if patches are up to date, others check hundreds if not thousands of settings and vulnerabilities.

Here's a short list http://netsecurity.about.com/od/freesecuritytools/a/aafreevulnscan.htm

One which isn't on that list is metasploit.  Metasploit will allow you to test if any of the machines on your network are vulnerable to a wide array of known attacks.

Comment: Good list. I was actually looking more for *free* programs, but this is probably one type of software that is hard to find without some monetary support with it.

Comment: Oh, and the list does say they are free, but most are trials. Metasploit is looking ok though.